# Progressbar spinner does not display

Tags: android, progress-bar, ui-thread

I have a problem with a progressbar spinner:

```
ProgressBarSpinner spinner = new ProgressBarSpinner();
spinner.execute(Spin);

Login LoginUser = new Login();
if(LoginUser.LoginUser(UserNameValue.getText().toString(), PasswordValue.getText().toString())) {
    MessageBox("Login information", "You've been successfully logged in, press OK to continue.");
    Document XMLInfo = null;
    Passphrase = PasswordValue.getText().toString();
    try {
        XMLInfo = XMLfromString(LoginUser.ProfileXML);
        XML_ProfileParser(XMLInfo);
        TickerString = FillProfileSlider(XMLInfo);              
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spin.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    TextView ProfileTicker = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProfileTicker);
    TextView UserInformation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NameInfo);
    TextView MoneyLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MoneyInfo);

    UserInformation.setText(ProfileInfo.get("FirstName") + " " + ProfileInfo.get("LastName"));
    MoneyLabel.setText(ProfileInfo.get("Money") + " Kr");

    if(Integer.parseInt(ProfileInfo.get("Messages")) >= 1) {
        ImageView MessageImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MailImage);
        MessageImage.setOnClickListener(ImageListener);
        MessageImage.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    }

    ProfileTicker.setText(Html.fromHtml(TickerString));
}
else {
    Spin.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
    MessageBox("Login information", "The submitted login information seems to be invalid.");
}
```

This gets executed when users click login. Spin is a global progressbar variable. Below is the Async class that is used to handle the spinner.

```
private class ProgressBarSpinner extends AsyncTask<ProgressBar, Integer, ProgressBar>
{

    protected ProgressBar doInBackground(ProgressBar...Spinner) {
        return Spinner[0];
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ProgressBar Spinner) {
        Spinner.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        Spinner.showContextMenu();
    }
}
```

To the problem: If I try to write

```
Spin.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
```

after the logins authorization the spinner does not get displayed at all. But if I remove the ProgressBar.Gone part the spinner is displayed.
But if that part is present is seems that the application "hangs" before it continues (either logging the user in or displaying an error message telling that the username or password is wrong).

What can the problem be?

I know for sure that the login is not done so fast that the spinner does not get time to be displayed before it is set to GONE.

Comment: Show all your code. Spinner can't be both an array and a Spinner.

Comment: I am curious as to why you are using an AsyncTask for managing UI.

Comment: I don't really get this, you should be showing the spinner right before calling your AsyncTask and hide it in onPostExecute, I'm not sure what your problem is the spinner is supposed to be entirely removed from the layout with View.GONE

Comment: @bbedward: Good point, I'll try that :)

Comment: @bbedward: Well, that actually fixed the problem, thanks to you all! :)

Comment: @Araw then i'll add an answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your spinner to visible before creating your AsyncTask and hide it in onPostExecute, something like:

```
mySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myAsyncTask.Execute(); // etc, etc
```

myAsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ProgressBar Spinner) {
    Spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```